# Top 3 Values in the Same Row

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I am working on Steam data and need to find the top 3 tags people used for each game but the problem is all the tag values are in the same row for each game like the image below (appid column then 370 column for each tag and values).

Result can be anything like 200,300,400 or column name plus tag value like action | 200, fps | 300, rpg | 400 etc. for each one of 36k games. The table looks like below and has around 36k games. I definitely **don't** want to find one column only or top 3 games.

Appid is unique and there are around 370 columns for each tag which I prepared in a proper format for SQL already. Could you please help me out?

[image]

Comment: Your image is unreadable.  Please provide sensible data in your question.

Comment: Could you please click it, sensible data is way more than I can upload or write in so even an example would be sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest unpivoting this table. Once you do that the query becomes trivial.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unpivot the data the query becomes trivial. To unpivot the data, you'll need to retrieve the table metadata and assemble a big SQL according the logic shown below. See the markers on the query below.

The solution will look like:

```
select
  *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by appid order by cnt desc) as rn
  from (
    -- unpivot the data using dynamic SQL
    select appid, "1980" as tag, [1980] as cnt from t union all
    select appid, "1990", [1990] from t union all
    select appid, "2_5d", [2_5d] from t union all
    select appid, "2d", [2d] from t union all
    select appid, "2d_fighter", [2d_fighter] from t union all
    ...
    select appid, "last_tag", [last_tag] from t
    -- finish unpivoting
  ) x
) y
where rn <= 3
order by appid, rn
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view to get all the columns names of that table.  With this you can easily generate some sql statements that get the data for you.

Other option would be to use SSIS or Power BI to pivot the data.